# Connect to remote JBoss with JMX behind a firewall

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jvisualvm

I have added the following properties to my JBOSS EAP 6.2 server;

```
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=94.5.19.27"
```

And have restarted jboss. When I try to connect to the instance using the following in JMX string in JVisualVM ( 94.5.19.27:9999 ) I get the following error message

[image]

Does anyone know which other configurations I might need to pass?

Thanks

**edit** if it were a firewall issue - would this return as follows;

```
[secondstory_dev@secondstory1d log]$ netstat -na | grep 9999
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: is your jboss server behind a firewall?  also, i assume it's a typo, but your first line is missing the closing quote.

Comment: Sorry the quote was a copy paste error, my server is behind a firewall. Maybe the port didn't open correctly

Answer (score 6):

There's a trick to getting rmi working behind a firewall.  rmi uses *two* ports, and if you don't specify *both* ports, it doesn't work through a firewall.  the nice part is that you can use the *same* port for both ports.  the annoying part is that this is not the *default* functionality.  even worse, until jdk 7, there was no way to configure jmx to do this using the command line.  assuming you are running on jdk 7+, you need to add this argument:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999
```

More details here http://realjenius.com/2012/11/21/java7-jmx-tunneling-freedom/ .

Comment: ahhh i was so excited thinking this might be the correct answer but i still get the same error message - it must be a firewall issue for me

Comment: @Biscuit128 - there may be _additional_ firewall issues, but this is also a requirement to get it working.  it presumes, of course, that your server is running on jdk 7u4 or later.

Comment: @Biscuit128 - is this a linux box, and does the "hostname" of the box resolve to the "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: the hostname resolves to the alias i named it - secondstory1d and yes it is fedora 20 and it is a box running locally on my network

Comment: @Biscuit128 - what does 'hostname -i' output?

Comment: 192.168.0.14 - the static address i assign on my network for it

Comment: @Biscuit128 - maybe it's an ipv6 thing.  your netstat output indicates it's listening on ipv6.  possibly something else doesn't like that?  if you don't need ipv6 support, what happens if you add "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to your jvm args?

Comment: I already have it in there -    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58639/discussion-between-biscuit128-and-jtahlborn).

Comment: @Biscuit128 - hmm, that's weird then, that it would be binding to a tcp6 addr.  one last shot, does `hostname -I' output anything interesting?

Comment: nope , same ip is displayed just an additional (what appears to be ) mac address

Answer (score 0):

You need add the option:

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false`

At restart, when you run "netstat" you can see that the port is not open only for localhost:

`$ netstat -na | grep 9999
tcp6       0      0 :::9999          :::*                    LISTEN`

Finally, you can validate with a telnet:

`telnet 94.5.19.27 9999`

If you could not connect is possible that you need to review your firewall, in linux:

`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9999/tcp`

I hope that this help you